# How to add to, not overwrite, an output on xcode

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nstextfield

I have a function that outputs a number to a multi-line text field. Currently, I set the contents of the text field with

```
[outputField setFloatValue:side];
```

(the name of the text field is "outputField" and the name of the variable I am putting in the text field is "side"). I don't think I can make "side" a string because I'm dividing two numbers to get the value of "side". Sorry if this is a dumb question it is my first xcode project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you want to add `side` to a new line preserving all the previous text and `side` is a float:

```
outputField.stringValue = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@\n%f",outputField.stringValue,side];
```

Answer (score -1):

```
outputField.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%f",outputField.text,side];
```

Comment: `NSTextField` doesn’t respond to `-setText:`.